# Using Masonry plugin from Backbone JS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jquery-masonry

I need to use the Masonry plugin to work with Backbone. Masonry works just fine when I generate the HTML statically but not with Backbone- so I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong with Backbone.

I am grabbing image URLs from an external API, rendering them, and then trying to call Masonry. I'm assuming that this should be done after all rendering, and I'm using ImagesLoaded.

JS:

```
app.WallView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#wall',

    initialize: function() {    

        this.collection = new app.ImageCollection();
        this.collection.fetch({reset: true});
        this.render();

        this.listenTo( this.collection, 'reset', this.render ); 
    },

    render: function() {

        this.collection.each(function( item ) {
            this.renderImage( item );
        }, this );

    var $container = $("#wall");
    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
        $container.masonry({
    });
});


    },

    renderImage: function( item ) {
        var imageView = new app.ImageView({
            model: item
        });
        this.$el.append( imageView.render().el );
    }
});

new app.WallView();
```

HTML snippet:

```
<div id="wall" class="images"></div>

<script type="text/template" id="image-template">
    <img src="<%= url %>"></img>
</script>
```